# How to book transportation in Bali?

Tags: transportation, bali

My wife and I booked a hotel in Bali (Legian, near Kuta) during the Chinese New Year. We plan to stay for three days and we wonder how we could book daily transportation, preferably small trucks/vans to bring us to different places on the island.

Do we need to book in advance?

Any clue how expensive/cheap it is?

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of drivers offering services in Bali, likely your hotel can recommend several if you ask.  But as you are going to be there during Chinese New Year, it might be good to arrange something in advance.

Costs run from 700,000 IDR on up for a day.  You pay for food, entry fees, etc. separately, gas may or may not be included.

You could try contacting Drivers of Distinction - http://distinctionbali.com as they are a good group of folks.  Dean, who runs it, is fairly selective of who can join up.  I have "stolen" all of the drivers for my company's cycling tours away from Dean .